# DataTables Request Unknown Parameter Error (Editor JS/CSS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatables

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I am building a CRUD application with aid from the DataTables API. I am trying to code add, edit and delete functionality manually, but the guys at DataTables said that it would be better to use Editor. So, I downloaded a trial version for JS and CSS for 15 days.

I only have 8 days left to use it and am having issues setting it up. My server data is not being pulled in from DataTables because I am receiving this error:

`DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Requested unknown parameter 'name' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`

I am not sure what this means, so I clicked on the link that appeared, but it doesn't make much sense as I have tried to make sure that I have the right columns inside the table. I am not sure what else could be causing the problem. I also ran the debugger, but I couldn't upload it to them since my webpage timed out from uploading the configuration.

Here is my javascript code and my html table code:

```
/*
 * Editor client script for DB table members
 * Created by http://editor.datatables.net/generator
 */

(function($){

$(document).ready(function() {
    var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: 'api/server.php',
        table: '#dataTable',
        fields: [       
            {
                "label": "Name:",
                "name": "name"
            },
            {
                "label": "Residential Address:",
                "name": "residential_address"
            },
            {
                "label": "Mailing Address:",
                "name": "mailing_address"
            },
            {
                "label": "Precinct:",
                "name": "precinct"
            },
            {
                "label": "Age:",
                "name": "age"
            },
            {
                "label": "Ethnicity:",
                "name": "ethnicity"
            },
            {
                "label": "Gender:",
                "name": "gender"
            },
            {
                "label": "Party:",
                "name": "party",
                "def": "REP"
            },
            {
                "label": "Race:",
                "name": "race"
            },
            {
                "label": "Phone:",
                "name": "phone"
            }
        ]
    } );

    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        order: [],
        pageLength: 25,
        ajax: 'api/server.php',
        columns: [      
            {
                "data": "name"
            },
            {
                "data": "residential_address"
            },
            {
                "data": "mailing_address"
            },
            {
                "data": "precinct"
            },
            {
                "data": "age"
            },
            {
                "data": "ethnicity"
            },
            {
                "data": "gender"
            },
            {
                "data": "party"
            },
            {
                "data": "race"
            },
            {
                "data": "phone"
            }
        ],
        select: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'create', editor: editor },
            { extend: 'edit',   editor: editor },
            { extend: 'remove', editor: editor }
        ]
    } );
} );

}(jQuery));
```

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Residential Address</th>
                      <th>Mailing Address</th>
                      <th>Precinct</th>
                      <th>Age</th>
                      <th>Ethnicity</th>
                      <th>Gender</th>
                      <th>Party</th>
                      <th>Race</th>
                      <th>Phone Number</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Residential Address</th>
                      <th>Mailing Address</th>
                      <th>Precinct</th>
                      <th>Age</th>
                      <th>Ethnicity</th>
                      <th>Gender</th>
                      <th>Party</th>
                      <th>Race</th>
                      <th>Phone Number</th>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
```

Here is my server.php file:

```
<?php

// DB table to use
$table = 'members';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    //array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'residential_address', 'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'mailing_address', 'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'precinct', 'dt' => 4),
    array( 'db' => 'age', 'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ethnicity',  'dt' => 6 ),
    array( 'db' => 'gender', 'dt' => 7 ),
    array( 'db' => 'party', 'dt' => 8 ),
    array( 'db' => 'race', 'dt' => 9 ),
    array( 'db' => 'phone', 'dt' => 10 )        
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => 'ccrp_db',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
?>
```

Let me know if any other code is needed. If I have it on hand, I'll be glad to share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say it in simple language

Data which you are passing to Datatable doesn't have any data with attr 'name'

Same is explained [here](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4)

If this doesnt help please add your sample data from `'api/server.php'`

eg:

```
{
    "residential_address" : "Address",
    "mailing_address" : "MailAddress",
    "userName" : "MyName"   
}
```

For above case if you try

```
columns: [      
    {
        "data": "name"
    }
]
```

you will get same error.

To resolve this you need to either change data field to `"data": "userName"`

or add name is JSON

```
{
    "residential_address" : "Address",
    "mailing_address" : "MailAddress",
    "name" : "MyName"   
}
```

Hope this helped.

**Edit 1:**

On providing more info. Looks like indexing is wrong. 
It has to be

```
array( 'db' => 'name',  'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'residential_address', 'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'mailing_address', 'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'precinct', 'dt' => 3),
array( 'db' => 'age', 'dt' => 4 ),
array( 'db' => 'ethnicity',  'dt' => 5 ),
array( 'db' => 'gender', 'dt' => 6 ),
array( 'db' => 'party', 'dt' => 7 ),
array( 'db' => 'race', 'dt' => 8 ),
array( 'db' => 'phone', 'dt' => 9 )
```

Refer to [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) for further detail if it still doesn't work

Comment: added more detail. pls check

Comment: I used this same example to create my server.php script.

Comment: Did you try with the index value I have suggested?

Comment: Yes, I get the same result.

Comment: In that case please inspect your request and add what data is being generated by 'api/server.php'

Comment: I have more than 45,000 records in the database. I cannot add them manually.

Comment: Add 10 sample records.

Comment: Just refer this https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side and inspect for server_processing.php and you will see response

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what to look for. I see this JS ```$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );``` Is this what I need or is my current JS taking care of that?

Comment: The server-side script that appears is identical to my server.php file. I don't understand how this is happening unless the server.php file is not being routed correctly.